# Intellij Project tree view, show helper lines between packages/directories

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, project-structure

Any way to show helper lines to better see hierarchy/tree structure of project? What i mean is :  [image]

To see more like this :

[image]

Is there some up to date plugin/ theme / settings that will show these lines in project view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend on the Look&Feel, currently the lines guides are not displayed for IntelliJ IDEA and Darcula themes, please vote for these requests:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165101
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144826
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152396

Comment: For anyone who doesn't feel like going through the links, this feature is scheduled for release in version 2018.3 (current version at the time of writing this is 2018.1)

Comment: I'm on the version 2018.3. Where do I find this option to turn on?

Comment: @ArthurEirich this option is still not available in 2018.3 version, follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165101 for updates.